# Is Session state ( server side ) safe to store some private data

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-core, session, server

I have a web app where the user logs in at the beginning of each session but I need to use his password for some encryption and decryption purposes so I need to keep it during the session duration.

I looked at the available solutions and all the client side storage are vulnerable to being hacked 
and many people suggested the use of server session state ( Memory )

But I am not very sure how really safe is it to store some highly sensitive data.
and if not are there any other options available to this case ???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not. But the real problem you have is that you've already settled on a flawed design:

> I need to use his password for some encryption and decryption purposes

As long as you rely on this assumption, you'll be looking for ways to store the user password in plain text or some reversible form, and that's simply unacceptable.

Comment: I think that you are right ..... I will try to look into some different design to deal with the problem